# "Putting" a JSON String back to a WEB API method hosted in a WebForms application

Tags: c#, json, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application. Within it I am successfully hosting Web API services which GET various bits of information. Now I need to PUT (update) an object. It is my understanding that I can send in a JSON string that, if it maps to a defined model/class can be received by the PUT method as an instance of that model/class.

So here's my model ...

```
[DataContract]
[Table("ServiceFeatures")]
public class ServiceFeature
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Int64 ServiceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String Comments { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Boolean? IsEnabled { get; set; }




    #region Navigation Property

    [ForeignKey("ServiceId")]
    public Service Service { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Here's the WebAPI method that is being called...

```
    [HttpPut]
    public void UpdateServiceFeature([FromBody]ServiceFeature value)
    {
        ServiceRepository.Instance.UpdateServiceFeature(value);
    }
```

And here's the JSON string being sent in the RequestBody of an AJAX request (from IE Dev Tools) ...

```
"{\"Id\":8,\"ServiceId\":3,\"Name\":\"Wrap \",\"Description\":\"Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc \",\"Comments\":\"sdfdsdssd\",\"DateAdded\":\"2013-07-29T23:39:19.46\",\"DateUpdated\":\"08/17/2013\",\"IsEnabled\":true}"
```

When the PUT request is submitted, I track the request through the WebAPI method and discovered that the value parameter is a DEFAULT instance of the ServiceFeature, where every property is set to NULL, rather than an instance filled with the data from the JSON String.

Am I missing something in how this is supposed to work or is this automatic mapping an MVC thing and WebForms requires a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

Both suggestions, the comment by "user2674389" to add the content-type "application/json", and the "answer" by Nenad to send the JSON as an OBJECT and not a STRING were required in order to make this work. I tried each individually so I could attribute the answer to the correct member but each were right. I have upvoted "user's" comment and marked Nenad's answer as "accepted". Thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you sent `application/json` as your content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending wrong format of data to WebAPI.
Assuming that you use jQuery to send PUT request, this is valid request (see `data` property):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Api/ServiceFeature',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
        "Id": 8,
        "ServiceId": 1,
        "Name": "Wrap",
        "Description": "Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc",
        "Comments": null,
        "DateAdded": "2013-08-17T22:40:53.2387243+02:00",
        "DateUpdated": "2013-08-17T00:00:00+02:00",
        "IsEnabled": true
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('Done');
    },
    error: function(textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

However, this is serialized into request body in this format:

```
Id=8&ServiceId=3&Name=Wrap&Description=Claritas+est+etiam+processus+dynamicus%2C+qui+sequitur+mutationem+consuetudium+lectorum.+Mirum+est+notare+quam+littera+gothica%2C+quam+nunc&Comments=sdfdsdssd&DateAdded=2013-07-29T23%3A39%3A19.46&DateUpdated=08%2F17%2F2013&IsEnabled=true
```

Content type is usually set by default correctly and it's `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

This is format that WebAPI expects in order to deserialize your object properly.